# Redeployment with Powershell in Multi Tenant Environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell, web-deployment

I want to redeploy a multiple tenants using powershell. We have 100+ tenants in UIT and I don't want to do this manually. In order to redeploy, I have to use a specific link and log in. My question is, if it is possible to do this in an automated way using powershell. Here is what I have so far:

```
Function SendRequest($tenantName)
{
     $url = "http://<machine-name>/$tenantName/Account  /LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2f$tenantName%2fadmin%2fdeploytenant%3fsyncmetadata%3dtrue&syncmetadata=true"    
     $req = [system.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
     $req.Credentials = [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::($username, (ConvertTo-SecureString $pwd  -AsPlainText -force)) 
     try 
     {
         $res = $req.GetResponse()

     } 
     catch [System.Net.WebException] 
     {
         $res = $_.Exception.Response
     }
     $int = [int]$res.StatusCode
     $status = $res.StatusCode
     Write-Host $status
     return "$int $status"
}
```

The status that is returned is "200 OK" but it does not redeploy. Maybe I need to log in first and then send another request with the redeployment parameters. So what would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is just a snippet of your code, but I'm seeing you reference `$username` and `$pwd` without actually feeding in a username and password.

Perhaps that could that explain the lack of a successful redeploy.

Comment: Those variables are initialized outside of this function.